# Realm of the Mad god is too laggy to play

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

So, I've been playing rotmg for a while, and am now getting quite frustrated at this lag. I will be in the godlands, trying to escape from a god, when the map doesn't load, and all the terrain starts disappearing. I try to escape to nexus; happens 2 minutes after I press my nexus escape key. Also, every time I get into a good dungeon, I "lag out" (go back to home screen unintentionally). I have tried switching servers around to less populated servers. I have a very good computer and 20+ MB internet speed. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: We could use more info. Are you using Flash Projector or Steam or a website? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Chrome? If so, I highly recommend that you disable PepperFlash. Go to the URL chrome://plugins, and find the plugin "Adobe Flash Player". Make sure you have Flash Player installed on your computer, or you will not be able to run Flash content after doing this. There should be 2 files under Adobe Flash Player, but the location of PepperFlash for me was this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application(a number)\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll

It might slightly vary, but disable that file. I did this and all my [rubber banding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_banding) and black tile lag had instantly stopped. You should stop getting kicked to the character select screen after this.

If you use another browser, I would recommend using [Adobe Flash Projector](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). RealmEye has a good tutorial [here](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/using-the-adobe-flash-projector-to-play-rotmg).

Comment: As a former Flash developer, I can confirm that PPAPI *(Pepper Flash)* is awful.  If you only have Pepper Flash in Chrome's plugins list, you need to install the NPAPI version of Flash from Adobe's website